# Laravel: Tracking page views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to implement a very simple page tracking system with Laravel, just to know which pages are most accessed.

At first I thought of create a table with access date, request URL (from `Request::path()`) and user id, as simple as that.

But I'd have to show page titles on reports, and for that I need some way to translate the request URI to its page title. Any ideas for that? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Currently I set page titles from Blade view files, through `@section('title', ...)`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Google Analytics to show pretty and very efficient reports. With the API, you can also customize the reports and (for example) show the pages titles.

If you want to develop it by yourself, I think that the best solution is to write an after filter that can be called after each page loading. One way of setting the title, in this case, is to use flash session variable (http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data) :

```
// routes.php
Route::group(array('after' => 'log'), function()
{
    Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');
}

// filters.php
Route::filter('log', function() {
    Log::create(array('title' => Session::get('title'), '...' => '...'));
}

// UserController.php
public function index()
{
    Session::flash('title', 'Users Page');
    // ...
}


// layout.blade.php
<head>
    <title>{{ Session::get('title') }}</title>
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, use a "after" filter for this. Do not think about anything else! :)

Comment: Agreed, go for google analytics, you won't be disappointed. It does everything and more for tracking with one line of code added to your template.

Comment: Yeah, I know I could use Google Analytics for that, but the costumer asked for a very simple (and built-in) page tracking system into the project and the filter & session trick did it nicely! Thank you again! :)

Comment: Now that laravel 5 is out, filters have been replaced by middleware. You can use middleware like an after filter for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered but I would like to add that I've published a package that can be easily implemented to track page views for Laravel (if they are Eloquent ORM instances) in specific date ranges: last day, week, month or all time.

**https://github.com/marcanuy/popularity**

Comment: i tried your package but i am getting an error with laravel 4.2:  Installation request for marcanuy/popularity ~1.0 -> satisfiable by marcanuy/popularity[1.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - marcanuy/popularity 1.0.0 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].